# Programmatically delete a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was wondering if someone could offer me some advice.

I have a master spreadsheet, acting as a template. I have written a script which can be run from the menu (using `addToUi` command), which makes a copy of template spreadsheet.

The problem is that the script gets copied into the new spreadsheet also which I don't want.

Could anyone suggest a possible way around this please?

I did think a possible way was to get the script to open the copied template and delete the script but not sure if this is possible.

Here is the function which does the copying....

```
function createCopy() {

var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B8").getValue();

var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

  DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).makeCopy(myValue,destinationFolder);

}
```

(Cell reference B8 holds the value of what I called the copied spreadsheet).

Comment: Do you have some code to show to us? If so, please edit your question and add it.

Comment: Sorry, yes here is the code that actually does the copying....

function createCopy() {

  var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("B8").getValue();
  
var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
  
DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).makeCopy(myValue,destinationFolder);
}

Comment: @Rayden You can use backticks `` on my keyboard they share the same key as the tilde ~.  If you surround code in comments with backticks the code is a little easier to read.  You can also use them in questions and answers but it works ever better to select the entire code and press control-k.

Comment: It may be possible to accomplish that with the Google Apps Script Rest API.  I'm not sure because I haven't used it yet.

Comment: @Cooper, thank you for that nugget! - I hadn't pasted code before and was wondering how it was done. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rayden, I use a function like that to just copy one sheet to a new spreadsheet and it doesn't drag the script with it. gDrive is the id for the Spreadsheet, tabName the individual sheet you want copied, Filename the name of the copy and destination the destination directory.

```
//******************************************************************************
//- This function takes a tab and makes it its own file
function tabToSheet(gDrive,tabName,fileName,destination){
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gDrive);
var ss = sh.getSheetByName(tabName);

//create a new document in the location given
var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("TEMPDELETEME");

//copy the tab from current document to new document 
ss.copyTo(newSheet);
var id = newSheet.getId();

newSheet.deleteSheet(newSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));
os = newSheet.getSheets()[0];
  os.setName(tabName);

var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination);


var finalId = file.makeCopy(fileName, folder).getId();
file.setTrashed(true);

return finalId;

}//*****************************************************************************
```

The difference is that i'm making a new sheet, then copying the tab rather than copying the entire file. You could add another tab and remove the variables if you want to copy multiple tabs.

Comment: I hadn't even considered your method, but just tested it and it works a charm.

Thank you so much!! Can you just explain the following code though please - not understanding how that bit works..



``newSheet.deleteSheet(newSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));

os = newSheet.getSheets()[0];

os.setName(tabName);``

Comment: Its so that you can control the location of the new sheet.  The steps are create temp, copy sheet to temp, copy temp to final location with specific name, delete temp sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble implementing J.G.'s approach of moving individual sheets, so the approach I took was to add a conditional in front of the script to only run if the spreadsheet id was equal to the id of the original spreadsheet. My use case was trying to suppress a custom menu on the original workbook from reappearing on the copy, so it worked for that.

```
var bookId = spreadsheet.getId();
if (bookId === 'original spreadsheet id') {
*Function*
  }
```